# How to properly start a Gnome-Shell extension via command line?

Tags: bash, shell, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

After copying `myexentension@me.com` folder to `.../gnome-shell/extensions/` I'm executing this command on the terminal:

`gnome-shell-extension-tool -e myexentension@me.com`

Then, I restart my session with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and execute `r`, and everything works fine.

But can I start my extension only through the command line? Without <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>+`r`? Without restarting my gnome-shell session?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to some answers around the internet, sending SIGHUP to the `gnome-shell` process restarts it (i. e. `killall -HUP gnome-shell`), but I haven’t been able to find a clear source on this and couldn’t find the signal handling in the code. What I do know is that this should be exactly equivalent to `Alt+F2 r`:

```
busctl --user call org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell Eval s 'Meta.restart("Restarting…")'
```

Because apart from a gettext call on the message, this is exactly what `Alt+F2 r` is bound to (see [`runDialog.js`](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/e64a482972c49176e6dd192332f0800acf2d4f0d/js/ui/runDialog.js) – search for `_restart`).

---

January 2022 update: Since Gnome 41, [calling Eval is restricted](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/commit/7298ee23e91b756c7009b4d7687dfd8673856f8b) and requires “unsafe mode” to be enabled, so by default this will no longer work. I’m not currently aware of a replacement for this particular usage.

Comment: This is exactly what i need. `killall` also killed my browser for some reason

Comment: @maxschlepzig I don’t see why it shouldn’t…

Comment: @LucasWerkmeister because `Alt`+`F2` `r` doesn't work under Wayland ...

Comment: Oh, right. Well, I just tried it out, and it looked like it did something and there was no obvious error message. (But the same is true when I run Alt+F2 r, so maybe that’s supported since a recent Gnome version? I’m on 3.38.)

Comment: @LucasWerkmeister regarding your concerns, the solution is in https://askubuntu.com/a/1376953/598062 . You might like to update your answer with this information.

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I prefer a solid <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> but maybe try disabling and enabling:

`gnome-shell-extension-tool -d myexentension@me.com && gnome-shell-extension-tool -e myexentension@me.com`

or

`gnome-shell-extension-tool -r myexentension@me.com`

Which may do the same thing. There's also `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` which you can use to do the same thing (and is typically hidden in Gnome for some reason).

Comment: Thanks Andy. But it doesn't update my extension without `Alt + F2, r+Enter` or restarting my system. If the extension is already installed, I found a command on Gnome DBus to update it. But if it's the first time how can I show the extension without restarting my session? 

I can't find a way to restart the session using the command line. If I use `gnome-shell --replace` I get a strange behavior if I close the terminal.

Comment: True, as far as I know Alt+F2, r+Enter is the only way to cleanly do it. I wouldn't worry about it much, and just do it that way.

Comment: @andy.holmes - `Alt`+`F2`, `R` `Enter` simply doesn't work if Gnome-Shell is running under Wayland ...

Comment: Correct, you have to restart the session if running under Wayland.

Answer (score 2):

`gnome-shell-extension-tool` is deprecated, use `gnome-extensions` instead. The command is:

```
gnome-extensions reset window-calls@domandoman.xyz && gnome-extensions enable window-calls@domandoman.xyz
```

If that does not work then try

```
killall -3 gnome-shell
```

I have a .desktop file that looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Restart Gnome
Icon=utilities-terminal
Exec=killall -3 gnome-shell
Categories=Utility;
```

I added it to the panel and just click the button when working on gnome extensions.

The official documentation for debugging and logging gnome extensions is [here](https://gjs.guide/extensions/development/debugging.html#reloading-extensions).