# How does gnome-browser-extension and chrome-gnome-shell load extension without reloading gnome session

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

[gnome-extensions](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/gnome-extensions.1.html) man page says:

> The command unpacks the extension files and moves them to the expected
> location in the
> user’s $HOME, so that it will be loaded in the next session.

so to install netspeed extension via script, we have to do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-extensions install --force netspeed@hedayaty.gmail.com.zip
killall -HUP gnome-shell
sleep 5s
gnome-extensions enable
```

Please check [How to properly start a Gnome-Shell extension via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46565019/1772898) for more details.

But the thing is, if we use [gnome-browser-extension](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/chrome-gnome-shell) and [chrome-gnome-shell](https://gitlab.gnome.org/nE0sIghT/chrome-gnome-shell) to install extensions from https://extensions.gnome.org/ , then it does not reload the gnome session. It just smoothly gets the work done.

I want to improve my script on [Command line tool to install GNOME Shell extensions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707840/206574). If i can implement the same mechanism to install extension without reloading gnome session then my script will be more polished. This is the context of this question.

So, how does gnome-browser-extension and chrome-gnome-shell load extension without reloading gnome session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install gnome extensions without reloading the gnome session, you have to run:

```
busctl --user call org.gnome.Shell.Extensions /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions org.gnome.Shell.Extensions InstallRemoteExtension s ${EXTENSION_ID}
```

or,

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Shell.Extensions /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.InstallRemoteExtension string:${EXTENSION_ID}
```